# api curl script is not giving output

Tags: shell, powershell

Below is the API call used from Powershell

```
$tokenrequest = @{ "grant_type" = "password"; "username" = $env:EMUsername; "password" =  $env:EMPassword }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL1 -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Headers @{ Authorization = ("OAuth2")} -Method POST -Body $tokenrequest
```

The same when converted to curl script is not giving any output

```
curl -X POST $URL1 -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-Length:1045" -H "Authorization:OAuth2" --data '{"grant_type":"password", "username":$env:EMUsername,"password":$env:EMPassword}' --write-out token
```

Comment: I presume you are running that curl in PowerShell as well? You have variables inside single quotes. Those won't expand and are taking as those literal strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

- First, as [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) points out, you're trying to reference environment variables such as `$env:EMUsername` in your string, yet **you're using `'...'`, i.e., a single-quoted string, in which no variable expansion (interpolation) takes place by design** - use `"..."` quoting instead.
- Next, in order **to embed string values such as `$env:EMUsername` in JSON text, they must be `"..."`-enclosed** _as part of the JSON text: e.g., `` "{ `"username`": `"$env:USERNAME`" }" ``
- Finally, unfortunately, **you must manually `\"`-escape all embedded `"` instances** to **ensure that they're recognized by *external programs* such as `curl`**; combined with PowerShell's own escaping of `"`, this means that **embedded `"` instances must be escaped as `` \`" ``** (sic; or `\""`; see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) for background).

To put it all together:

```
$json = "{
  \`"grant_type\`": \`"password\`",
  \`"username\`": \`"$env:EMUsername\`",
  \`"password\`": \`"$env:EMPassword\`"
}"

curl -X POST $URL1 -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
     -H "Content-Length:1045" -H "Authorization:OAuth2" `
     --data $json --write-out token
```